# Baking issues causing image textures to lose transparency

Tags: texturing, scripting, uv, node-editor, transparency

I am currently writing the code for an add-on that would merge and bake certain objects on a mesh and then reapply these new baked textures onto the original mesh with the goal of everything looking the exact same as it was before the baking process. I currently have an issue where my code bakes 4 maps (Diffuse, Rougness, Specular, and Normal) and correctly lines everything up to the principled BSDF node. The problem is that my baked images look a little off as the sometimes the maps are applied and the mesh is paler than it once was and also the eyelashes are completely losing its transparency. I tried to remedy this by dragging the alpha port from my diffuse image texture into the alpha node on the principled BSDF node but it still is not transparent. Is there any ways to remedy this, I tried upping the max bounces for transparency under the render light paths settings but it did nothing. I also tried copying the diffuse image texture and having color get plugged into alpha as well which gave me some horrifying results. Is there something else I have to bake or connect additional nodes to retain my original transparency? Many thanks!

[image]

[image]
Note: In the bottom right of this color map are the eyelashes that I am trying to get working, I think the cause of the issue might be the fact that the UV map isnt actually the strand of hair but instead a big shape like the one shown on the eye which is supposed to be transparent and only leave strands of color behind.

[image]

Note: Original Eyelash map that I am baking from (I am trying to combine multiple materials into one)

```
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
    bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 1
    bpy.context.scene.render.bake.use_pass_direct = False
    bpy.context.scene.render.bake.use_pass_indirect = False
    bpy.context.scene.render.bake.margin = 1

    #Baking the file path 
    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='DIFFUSE', save_mode='EXTERNAL')
    img.save_render(filepath=colorMap)

    #Switch bake settings to SRGB to Non-Color
    for mat in obj.data.materials:
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE' and node.label.startswith(image_name):
                node.image.colorspace_settings.name = 'Non-Color'
                break

    #Baking the normal map
    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='NORMAL', save_mode='EXTERNAL')
    img.save_render(filepath=normalMap)
    #Baking the roughness and specular maps
    bpy.ops.object.bake(type='ROUGHNESS', save_mode='EXTERNAL')
    img.save_render(filepath=roughnessMap)

    #Inverting the roughness map in order to create the specular map
    image = bpy.data.images.get(img.name) 
    override = bpy.context.copy()
    override["edit_image"] = image
    bpy.ops.image.invert(override, invert_r=True, invert_g=True, invert_b=True)
    image.save_render(filepath=specularMap)
```

[image]
That is a picture of the node tree once my code is applying the new baked textures